# What´s best practice to responsive design? Use % or em and rem?

Tags: responsive-design

What´s best practice for layout responsive?, I read some articles that´s recommend use em and rem´s for layout, foundation 5 for example use this practice.

What do you think?

Comment: The design is responsive by using media queries, the design is fluid using percentages and/or ems. You combine those methods.